# How to use R in allocating a vector of 10.7 Gb

Tags: r, vector, error-handling, txt

```
# set seed for reproducability
set.seed(660067)
# sample all three data sets
sampleBlogs <- sample(blogs, length(blogs) * sampleSize, replace = FALSE)
sampleNews <- sample(news, length(news) * sampleSize, replace = FALSE)
sampleTwitter <- sample(twitter, length(twitter) * sampleSize, replace = FALSE)
# remove all non-English characters from the sampled data
sampleBlogs <- iconv(sampleBlogs, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")
sampleNews <- iconv(sampleNews, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")
sampleTwitter <- iconv(sampleTwitter, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")
# combine all three data sets into a single data set and write to disk
sampleData <- c(sampleBlogs, sampleNews, sampleTwitter)
sampleDataFileName <- "data/final/en_US/en_US.sample.txt"
con <- file(sampleDataFileName, open = "w")
writeLines(sampleData, con)
close(con)
# get number of lines and words from the sample data set
sampleDataLines <- length(sampleData);
sampleDataWords <- sum(stri_count_words(sampleData))
# remove variables no longer needed to free up memory
rm(blogs, news, twitter, sampleBlogs, sampleNews, sampleTwitter)
```

```
library(tm)
# download bad words file
# badWordsURL <- "https://www.freewebheaders.com/full-list-of-bad-words-banned-by-google/base-list-of-bad-words_text-file_2021_01_18.zip"
badWordsFile <- "data/base-list-of-bad-words_text-file_2021_01_18.txt"
if (!file.exists('data')) {
    dir.create('data')
}
if (!file.exists(badWordsFile)) {
    tempFile <- tempfile()
    download.file(badWordsURL, tempFile)
    unzip(tempFile, exdir = "data")
    unlink(tempFile)
}
buildCorpus <- function (dataSet) {
    docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource(dataSet))
    toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
    
    # remove URL, Twitter handles and email patterns
    docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@[^\\s]+")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\b[A-Z a-z 0-9._ - ]*[@](.*?)[.]{1,3} \\b")
    
    # remove profane words from the sample data set
    con <- file(badWordsFile, open = "r")
    profanity <- readLines(con, encoding = "UTF-8", skipNul = TRUE)
    close(con)
    profanity <- iconv(profanity, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, profanity)
    
    docs <- tm_map(docs, tolower)
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
    docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
    docs <- tm_map(docs, PlainTextDocument)
    return(docs)
}
# build the corpus and write to disk (RDS)
corpus <- buildCorpus(sampleData)
saveRDS(corpus, file = "data/final/en_US/en_US.corpus.rds")
# convert corpus to a dataframe and write lines/words to disk (text)
corpusText <- data.frame(text = unlist(sapply(corpus, '[', "content")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
con <- file("data/final/en_US/en_US.corpus.txt", open = "w")
writeLines(corpusText$text, con)
close(con)
kable(head(corpusText$text, 10),
      row.names = FALSE,
      col.names = NULL,
      align = c("l"),
      caption = "First 10 Documents") %>% kable_styling(position = "left")
# remove variables no longer needed to free up memory
rm(sampleData)
```

```
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
freq <- sort(rowSums(as.matrix(tdm)), decreasing = TRUE)
wordFreq <- data.frame(word = names(freq), freq = freq)
# plot the top 10 most frequent words
g <- ggplot (wordFreq[1:10,], aes(x = reorder(wordFreq[1:10,]$word, -wordFreq[1:10,]$fre),
                                  y = wordFreq[1:10,]$fre ))
g <- g + geom_bar( stat = "Identity" , fill = I("grey50"))
g <- g + geom_text(aes(label = wordFreq[1:10,]$fre), vjust = -0.20, size = 3)
g <- g + xlab("")
g <- g + ylab("Word Frequencies")
g <- g + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5),
               axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = 45),
               axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5))
g <- g + ggtitle("10 Most Frequent Words")
print(g)
# construct word cloud
suppressWarnings (
    wordcloud(words = wordFreq$word,
              freq = wordFreq$freq,
              min.freq = 1,
              max.words = 100,
              random.order = FALSE,
              rot.per = 0.35, 
              colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
)
# remove variables no longer needed to free up memory
rm(tdm, freq, wordFreq, g)
```

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 10.7 Gb

I am working on a project to audit out profanity and unnecessary characters from a series of text files with R. But the following error popped up as I was loading the 'freq' function. How can I solve this?
Use this link to look through the R file on Github (feel free to copy & paste):
https://github.com/Lionel-Courteau/Data-Science-Coursera-Capstone/blob/main/mark2.Rmd

Comment: R operates by holding all data in memory. You need to have enough RAM for the data you want to analyze. The error message you get does not indicate the total amount of RAM R was requesting, it's just the size of the attempted last allocation that failed. It's unclear exactly what line is triggering that error. But you may either need to subset to a smaller number of records or upgrade to a compute with more memory.

Comment: Can you indicate which lines throws the memory issue; if i had to guess it would be the line `freq <- sort(rowSums(as.matrix(tdm)), decreasing = TRUE)` -- this will convert a sparse matrix to a dense which will be ram costly. There are sparse rowSums method that can avoid the `as.matrix`.

Comment: Yes, the line  ```freq <- sort(rowSums(as.matrix(tdm)), decreasing = TRUE)``` does throw the memory issue. What kind of rowSums methods can you recommend?

Comment: I _think_ `tm` uses the sparse matrices from the `slam` package, so try using `slam::row_sums`

Comment: ```slam::row_sums``` doesn't work. I still get the memory issue